# pg_query warning

Tags: php

Olá, estou recebendo um warning de chave duplicada, com o código abaixo, tentei capturar essa mensagem de algumas formas mas não consegui, eu quero poder analisar esse warning antes que ele imprima algo na tela. 
Se for chave duplicada eu não vou imprimir nada pro usuário, mas se for outro erro quero imprimir o erro para o usuário.

```
    if ($consulta = pg_query($sql)){
        echo htmlspecialchars($sql) . " -- ".$arquivo." -  SQL OK<br>\n";
    }
```

Já tentei o codigo abaixo mas nesse caso ele me imprime 2x o erro.

```
    if ($consulta = pg_query($sql)){
        echo htmlspecialchars($sql) . " -- ".$arquivo." -  INSERIDO <br>\n";
    }else{
        echo htmlspecialchars($sql) . " -- ".$arquivo." -  FALHA NO SQL <br>\n";
            if (! (strrpos(pg_last_error(), "duplicate key") ) ) {
                echo "<b>ERRO --> ".pg_last_error()."</b><br />";
            } 
    }
```

Se eu deixar somente o primeiro codigo ele continua imprimindo o warning.

Comment: Como no seu primeiro exemplo aparece "chave duplicada" se nem há essa *string* no código?

Comment: isso mesmo, quando eu rodo a consulta está me dando um warning de duplicated key, sem eu prever isso.
Tentei o pg_query($sql) or die ( ..... ) mas não pegou também...

Comment: Ah, então existe um *warning* na jogada. Por favor, edite a pergunta e adicione a mensagem.

Comment: Verifique na sua tabela se a coluna que é a primary key está com o auto increment ativado.

Comment: está sim, o problema não é a chave duplicada, o problema é que não consigo pegar o warning, preciso saber se existe alguma forma de pegar esse warning.
O pg_last_error pega, mas só pega depois que ele já foi impresso.

Comment: Fundamental pra mexer com PHP é acessar o log de erros